# how to compare two list in Python

Tags: python

My project is related to magazines. List1 has titles and volume ID, list2 has title and page numbers. I need page numbers.

```
list1 = [('title1','101010'), ('title2','101020'), ('title3','101030')]  
list2 = [('title1','01'), ('title2','02'), ('title3','03')]
```

I need `('title1', '01')` and `('title','02')`. I am confirming titles by using volume id, then I want page numbers as result. I don't want title3 because it isn't in my database.

Comment: That's not clear at all - why those two? Have you tried implementing this? What happened?

Comment: No, it's not. Don't you have those already in `list2`? Also, pls post actual Python data structures. E.g. `abc` is not defined.

Comment: I think that it would be necessary to specify the variables you're using (what's abc, exactly? a string or a variable?). Also, could you please check the code? I pasted the list directly to jupyter notebook and it gave me back some spelling errors, such as '02' and that kind of stuff.

Comment: Where are you comparing anything?

Comment: Now it is. Am I wrong?

Comment: Why don't you want `('title3', '03')` too?

Comment: I clarify it, anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer to unmodified question:

You can accomplish this with a for loop.

```
#using for loop 
list1 = [("abc",10), ("def",20), ("ghi",30)]  
list2 = [("abc",1), ("ghi",2), ("jkl",3)]

for title_vol in list1:
  title = title_vol[0]
  for title_paged in list2:
    if title in title_paged:
      print(title_paged)
#('abc', 1), ('ghi', 2)
```

This is okay if it's just for simple list comparism. But if you're looking to store multiple items for one variable, I'd recommend using a Python [Dictionary](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)

```
#example using dictionary
magazine = [
  {
    "title": "abc",
    "vol": 10,
    "page": 1,
  },
  {
    "title": "def",
    "vol": 20,
    "page": 30,
  },
]

#accessing elements
for segment in magazine:
  print(segment)
```

You can access the elements further as you wish. Like just the pages, etc. with simple loops.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```py
titles = set([title for title, _ in list1])
[(title, pageNum) for title, pageNum in list2 if title in titles]
# [('abc', '01'), ('ghi', '02')]
```

Comment: You could get the same result with the shorter `titles = dict(list1)` :-)